# R: ggplot2 scalebar in miles

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I'v been trying to find a good function to create a scalebar in miles for some maps I made. However, all the packages I have found only allow you to have the scalebar in km. I need it in miles. I came across the scale_bar function from

```
devtools::install_github("3wen/legendMap")
```

which allows you to change the units to miles. I have been playing around with the arguments to get it to work all morning but nothing seems to make it work. I would appreciate it if anyone can help me resolve this issue or know of any packages that can do this. Thanks in advance.

```
graph1<-ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(data=middlestates,colour="black",fill="#D3D3D3",aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group))+
  geom_polygon(data=df,colour="black",aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group,fill=ALG))+
  ggtitle("Figure 2.2A: Assessment Results for\nGeneral Aquatic Life Use, Spatial Extent")+
  xlab("")+
  ylab("")+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(200000.732,905000.646), ylim=c(-5812.321,900000.543))+
  #ggsn::scalebar(df,location="bottomleft",dist = 50,st.dist=0.02,st.size=3, height=0.01)+
  scale_fill_manual("Aquatic Life Designated\nUse 2014 Assessment",values=c((values=c(colors))))+
  cowplot::background_grid(major= "none",minor = "none") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position=c(0.8,0.2),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill=NA),
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size=12),
        legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=12, face="bold"),
        plot.title=element_text(size=15, face="bold",hjust=0.5))
graph1+scale_bar(lon =200000.732, lat = -5812.321,distance_lon = 1,distance_lat = 5,distance_legend = 2,dist_unit = "mi", orientation = FALSE)
```

The plot I'm getting (scale bar in bottom left corner):
[image: The scale bar is in the bottom left corner]

Comment: package ggsn also has a scalebar, but you would need to edit the function to show imperial units

Comment: @RichardTelford Yeah I tried using that but it only has km.. how would I be able to edit the function?